# Laravel4 directory structure for packages

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

When creating a package in Laravel4 using the 'php artisan workbench' command, there is a pretty strange structure used. Like this:

```
project/workbench/MyName/MyPackage/src
        /MyName
          /MyPackage
             PackageServiceProvider.php
        /config
        /lang
        /migrations
        /views
        /tests
        /public
```

Especially I´m wondering, why the MyName/MyPackage/src/MyName/MyPackage is created.

Why is the package structure created like this? And why does it look so redundant?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does Laravel4 store the same vendor-files over and over again?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26403759/why-does-laravel4-store-the-same-vendor-files-over-and-over-again)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first `MyName/MyPackage` is for the name of the package and it is definitely needed to make sure it doesn't collide with any other package when being installed using composer (inside the `vendor` directory)

The second `MyName/MyPackage` is not necessarily needed. It is created this way because it matches the namespace of your package.

```
MyName/MyPackage => MyName\MyPackage
```

You can change this at your will but you might will have to change the `composer.json` file (of your package) according to your setup so the classes still get *autoloaded*